# How can I replace increment operators when using NSInteger and int properties

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am updating some old code to our new coding standards. In this code, the `int` variable was incremented with the old `++` operator. Now, the `int` variable is a property so using `++` isn't working so well. I'm not supposed to use dots and I'm not supposed to reference ivars directly.
Here is what I have come up with (totalHeads is the property of type `int`):
declaration section

```
@synthesize totalHeads = _totalHeads;
```

further down

```
[self setTotalHeads:[self totalHeads] + 1];
```

which replaces the old code of

```
_totalHeads ++;
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?
(apologies if this is a duplicate question, I was having a hard time figuring out good search terms)

Comment: Does `[self setTotalHeads:self.totalHeads++];` work? I'm not suggesting it's better, just curious.

Comment: `self.totalHeads += 1;` should be a perfectly valid replacement.

Comment: If I read our new standards correctly, we are a "no dots ever" shop now. Sorry, I wasn't clear about that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as you've mentioned in the comments, you're not allowed to use dot syntax to access setter methods, then `[self setTotalHeads:[self totalHeads] + 1];` is the only way to do it.

Coding standards that disallow use of language features under all circumstances are unproductive. Maybe you can use this example to make your case.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the property and the postincrement operator. This code:

```
@interface Foo: NSObject
@property (assign) int bar;
@end

@implementation Foo
@synthesize bar;
@end

int main() {
    Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
    foo.bar = 3;
    foo.bar++;
    NSLog(@"foo.bar: %d", foo.bar);
    [foo release];
    return 0;
}
```

produces this result:

> 2011-06-21 21:17:53.552 Untitled[838:903] foo.bar: 4

Comment: I'm sorry, I left out the really important part of my question. I'm not supposed to use dots.

Comment: Then fix your coding standards so that you can use the language features efficiently, then follow the code sample above ;-)

Comment: I'll take that as a "no" to my original question then :-). It will be a good counter example when I get asked why I want the standards to change.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter that's a property - it's still an int and, unless you declare a different name for ivar associated with the property, you can still use totalHeads++;

Comment: We do use a different prefix for the ivars. Regardless, we're not supposed to access them directly now, only through properties.

Comment: Maybe you should challenge the rules then... or change your job :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on a question about converting between NSInteger and int, I came up with the following:

```
- (NSInteger) incrementNSInteger: (NSInteger) nsInt byNumber: (int)increment
{
    int integer = nsInt;
    integer += increment;
    NSInteger result = integer;

    return result;
}
```

To use:

```
NSInteger one;
NSInteger two = [self incrementNSInteger: one byNumber: 1];
```

If you supply "byNumber" with -1, it'll decrement.  Similarly, 2 increments by 2, -2 decrements by 2.  (Why ++ and -- aren't sufficient baffles me).